# Is it possible to interact with Gnosis contracts directly without any APIs?

Tags: gnosis-safe, proxy-contracts

If for some reason Gnosis is down can I interact with the contracts directly?

Comment: what do you mean by other way of interact directly? The api is the only way to call the function from the contract

Comment: Ah thanks, so I can't call the contracts directly with a script, right?

Answer (score 1):

It is absolutely possible. That's the whole point of smart contracts.

You can use the following:

1. JavaScript SDK for scripts - https://github.com/safe-global/safe-core-sdk
2. CLI tool that doesn't depend on any APIs - https://github.com/5afe/safe-cli